# Handling CONNECT requests with node.js express module

Tags: node.js, http, express, httprequest

My node app is receiving some mysterious `CONNECT` requests and I'm trying to get to the bottom of where these are coming from (see separate post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33370798/4070848)).

I'm using the [express module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and until now, incoming `CONNECT` requests would just be fended off automatically with a `503` response.

But now, in order to examine the headers of these `CONNECT` requests, I'm trying to implement handling of such requests using the `express` module, if only just to dump the headers to the console and then send a `503` response myself.

Given the `express` seems to provide handling of `connect` as well as `get` and `post` (see [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.METHOD)), this is what I've tried so far:

```
var connectHandler = function(req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    res.sendStatus(503);
};

var app = express();
app.connect('*', connectHandler);
```

But the behaviour of the node app doesn't change... i.e. nothing is dumped to console when an incoming `CONNECT` request is received, with the `CONNECT` request being fended off and with the following entry in the log (just as before):

```
Oct 27 14:14:25 example heroku/router: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=CONNECT path="example.herokuapp.com:443" host=example.herokuapp.com request_id=353e623x-dec4-42x5-bcfb-452add02ecef fwd="111.22.333.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the CONNECT request if you use a generic middleware (e.g. `app.use()`) ?

Comment: Good suggestion @mscdex.  But when I do something like `app.use(function (req, res, next) { console.log(req.method, JSON.stringify(req.headers)); next(); });` it *is* seeing e.g. `HEAD` requests from a ping service I'm using, but unfortunately it does *not* seem to be seeing the `CONNECT` requests.

Comment: Ok, if you have that test generic middleware *at the top* of your Express router stack and you're not seeing the CONNECT requests, then something else is at play here.

Comment: Yep, I was starting to think the same, so I've already put in a question to heroku to see if they can understand what's going on, and whether their system is somehow intercepting CONNECTs before they even get to my app

Comment: The reply from heroku (who, as ever, are amazing) explains it all: "as described in our routing docs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#supported-http-methods), we support all HTTP verbs except the CONNECT verb. So, the response being sent is from our router – not your application. That explains why your application is never receiving the request."  So the generic middleware solution above would probably (normally) work, and maybe even the `app.connect()` approach in my question... I'll probably never know!

Comment: Technically both of them should work in a normal/unrestricted environment.